Why should we use ray casting?
Recently, I implemented a ray casting algorithm to determine whether a point is inside the area enclosed by a general, non-self-intersecting polygonal line on a plane. I chose this strategy because I thought it was simple and reliable.
However, I'm wondering if we can (or we should) solve the same problem as in the convex case, where it is sufficient to check an inequality in the form Ax <= b, where the matrix A and the vector b are defined by the polygonal line, while x is the point under test.
